# Using cPanel to move email address

Tags: email, cpanel

How can I delete the: `old_mail_address@domain.com` and move to `new_mail_address@domain.com` in cPanel?

So that when a user sends an email to the `old_mail_address@domain.com` it will be directly forwarded to `new_mail_address@domain.com` and there's no error while sending that mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solved it, I just create new mail address with new domain name and then forward message to the new mail address.
Example:

1. **Old mail address** : manellen@old-address.com
2. Create **New mail address** : manellen@new-address.com
3. **Forward messages** from old mail address to new mail address

From this case, we can see that one user has two mail address that is old mail address and new mail address. My reason about that is to avoid failed send messages or people can't send message to old mail address then I'm not delete the old mail address.